# Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty - Two Wordpress sites exactly the same, same plugin, different result

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a perplexing issue - I have two sites that are cloned, and they are both using the same custom plugin to upload a csv file to update values in a mysql database. Now there is no empirical difference between the two websites but the plugin works for one and not the other.

The error thrown is:

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 20 of the file .../wp-content/plugins/Balance_Update-1/displaylist.php. Error message: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in .../wp-content/plugins/Balance_Update-1/displaylist.php:20

Stack trace:

#0 .../wp-content/plugins/Balance_Update-1/displaylist.php(20): fopen('', 'r')

#1 .../wp-content/plugins/Balance_Update-1/balance-update.php(21): include('/usr/www/users/...')

#2 .../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): displayList('')

#3 .../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)

#4 .../wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)

#5 .../wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action('toplevel_page_b...')

#6 {main}
thrown

As you can see in the trace, fopen comes up blank for one of the two cloned websites:

```
fopen('', 'r')
```

The code, up until line 20 is:

```
global $wpdb;

// Table name
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix."fswcwallet";

// Import CSV
if(isset($_POST['butimport'])){

    // File extension
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['import_file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // If file extension is 'csv'
    if(!empty($_FILES['import_file']['name']) && $extension == 'csv'){

        $totalInserted = 0;
        $totalUpdated = 0;

        // Open file in read mode
        $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
```

Any thoughts on what could be different that would cause this to happen? I am not even sure where to begin looking.

Thank you

Comment: Please login in as root and post TEXT results from each server involved A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and from the OS Command Prompt, ulimit -a;  for list of OS limits - for analysis and C) the LAST 100 line from each servers Error.log..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems it was a server setup error, there was no .tmp file setup in the home directory so the path was empty as not file was locally stored during the upload.